# CSS / SVG / Animation: Как применить transform origin к одному элементу в SVG

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation, anime.js

Я хочу анимировать определенные части (полигоны) SVG, используя [animejs](http://animejs.com/).

Например, я хочу, чтобы каждый отдельный многоугольник вращался вокруг своего центра или увеличивался от 0,1 до 1,0.

Моя проблема в том, что многоугольники вращаются не вокруг своего собственного центра, а вокруг верхнего левого угла всей SVG.

Я изучил эту статью о «[Transforms on SVG Elements](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/)» и выяснил, что `transform-origin` связано с моей проблемой. Но даже если я установлю `transform-origin: 50% 50%`, источником анимации для каждого многоугольника будет центр всего SVG, а не отдельные многоугольники SVG.

```js
anime({
  targets: 'polygon, polyline',
  scale: [0.1, 1],
  opacity: [0.1, 1],
  rotate: '1turn',
  duration: 7000
});
```

```css
body, html{
  margin:0
}
svg, g {
  transform-origin: unset unset;
}

polygon, polyline {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1"
  id="heroSvg" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 1920 1300"
  style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1300;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
 .st1{fill:url(#SVGID_2_);}
 .st2{fill:url(#SVGID_3_);}
 .st3{fill:url(#SVGID_4_);}
 .st4{fill:url(#SVGID_5_);}
 .st5{fill:url(#SVGID_6_);}
 .st6{fill:url(#SVGID_7_);}
 .st7{fill:url(#SVGID_8_);}
 .st8{fill:url(#SVGID_9_);}
 .st9{fill:url(#SVGID_10_);}
 .st10{fill:url(#SVGID_11_);}
 .st11{fill:url(#SVGID_12_);}
 .st12{fill:url(#SVGID_13_);}
 .st13{fill:url(#SVGID_14_);}
 .st14{fill:url(#SVGID_15_);}
 .st15{fill:url(#SVGID_16_);}
 .st16{fill:url(#SVGID_17_);}
 .st17{fill:url(#SVGID_18_);}
 .st18{fill:url(#SVGID_19_);}
 .st19{fill:url(#SVGID_20_);}
 .st20{fill:url(#SVGID_21_);}
 .st21{fill:url(#SVGID_22_);}
 .st22{fill:url(#SVGID_23_);}
 .st23{fill:url(#SVGID_24_);}
 .st24{fill:url(#SVGID_25_);}
 .st25{fill:url(#SVGID_26_);}
 .st26{fill:url(#SVGID_27_);}
 .st27{fill:url(#SVGID_28_);}
 .st28{fill:url(#SVGID_29_);}
 .st29{fill:url(#SVGID_30_);}
 .st30{fill:url(#SVGID_31_);}
 .st31{fill:url(#SVGID_32_);}
 .st32{fill:url(#SVGID_33_);}
 .st33{fill:url(#SVGID_34_);}
 .st34{fill:url(#SVGID_35_);}
 .st35{fill:url(#SVGID_36_);}
 .st36{fill:url(#SVGID_37_);}
 .st37{fill:url(#SVGID_38_);}
 .st38{fill:url(#SVGID_39_);}
 .st39{fill:url(#SVGID_40_);}
 .st40{fill:url(#SVGID_41_);}
 .st41{fill:url(#SVGID_42_);}
 .st42{fill:url(#SVGID_43_);}
 .st43{fill:url(#SVGID_44_);}
 .st44{fill:url(#SVGID_45_);}
 .st45{fill:url(#SVGID_46_);}
 .st46{fill:url(#SVGID_47_);}
 .st47{fill:url(#SVGID_48_);}
 .st48{fill:url(#SVGID_49_);}
 .st49{fill:url(#SVGID_50_);}
 .st50{fill:url(#SVGID_51_);}
 .st51{fill:url(#SVGID_52_);}
 .st52{fill:url(#SVGID_53_);}
 .st53{fill:url(#SVGID_54_);}
 .st54{fill:url(#SVGID_55_);}
 .st55{fill:url(#SVGID_56_);}
 .st56{fill:url(#SVGID_57_);}
 .st57{fill:url(#SVGID_58_);}
 .st58{fill:url(#SVGID_59_);}
 .st59{fill:url(#SVGID_60_);}
 .st60{fill:url(#SVGID_61_);}
 .st61{fill:url(#SVGID_62_);}
 .st62{fill:url(#SVGID_63_);}
 .st63{fill:url(#SVGID_64_);}
 .st64{fill:url(#SVGID_65_);}
 .st65{fill:url(#SVGID_66_);}
 .st66{fill:url(#SVGID_67_);}
 .st67{fill:url(#SVGID_68_);}
 .st68{fill:url(#SVGID_69_);}
 .st69{fill:url(#SVGID_70_);}
 .st70{fill:url(#SVGID_71_);}
 .st71{fill:url(#SVGID_72_);}
 .st72{fill:url(#SVGID_73_);}
 .st73{fill:url(#SVGID_74_);}
 .st74{fill:url(#SVGID_75_);}
 .st75{fill:url(#SVGID_76_);}
 .st76{fill:url(#SVGID_77_);}
 .st77{fill:url(#SVGID_78_);}
 .st78{fill:url(#SVGID_79_);}
 .st79{fill:url(#SVGID_80_);}
 .st80{fill:url(#SVGID_81_);}
 .st81{fill:url(#SVGID_82_);}
 .st82{fill:url(#SVGID_83_);}
 .st83{fill:url(#SVGID_84_);}
 .st84{fill:url(#SVGID_85_);}
 .st85{fill:url(#SVGID_86_);}
 .st86{fill:url(#SVGID_87_);}
 .st87{fill:url(#SVGID_88_);}
 .st88{fill:url(#SVGID_89_);}
 .st89{fill:url(#SVGID_90_);}
 .st90{fill:url(#SVGID_91_);}
 .st91{fill:url(#SVGID_92_);}
 .st92{fill:url(#SVGID_93_);}
 .st93{fill:url(#SVGID_94_);}
 .st94{fill:url(#SVGID_95_);}
 .st95{fill:url(#SVGID_96_);}
 .st96{fill:url(#SVGID_97_);}
 .st97{fill:url(#SVGID_98_);}
 .st98{fill:url(#SVGID_99_);}
 .st99{fill:url(#SVGID_100_);}
 .st100{fill:url(#SVGID_101_);}
 .st101{fill:url(#SVGID_102_);}
 .st102{fill:url(#SVGID_103_);}
 .st103{fill:url(#SVGID_104_);}
 .st104{fill:url(#SVGID_105_);}
 .st105{fill:url(#SVGID_106_);}
 .st106{fill:url(#SVGID_107_);}
 .st107{fill:url(#SVGID_108_);}
 .st108{fill:url(#SVGID_109_);}
 .st109{fill:url(#SVGID_110_);}
 .st110{fill:url(#SVGID_111_);}
 .st111{fill:url(#SVGID_112_);}
 .st112{fill:url(#SVGID_113_);}
 .st113{fill:url(#SVGID_114_);}
 .st114{fill:url(#SVGID_115_);}
 .st115{fill:url(#SVGID_116_);}
 .st116{fill:url(#SVGID_117_);}
 .st117{fill:url(#SVGID_118_);}
 .st118{fill:url(#SVGID_119_);}
 .st119{fill:url(#SVGID_120_);}
 .st120{fill:url(#SVGID_121_);}
 .st121{fill:url(#SVGID_122_);}
 .st122{fill:url(#SVGID_123_);}
 .st123{fill:url(#SVGID_124_);}
 .st124{fill:url(#SVGID_125_);}
 .st125{fill:url(#SVGID_126_);}
 .st126{fill:url(#SVGID_127_);}
 .st127{fill:url(#SVGID_128_);}
 .st128{fill:url(#SVGID_129_);}
 .st129{fill:url(#SVGID_130_);}
 .st130{fill:url(#SVGID_131_);}
 .st131{fill:url(#SVGID_132_);}
 .st132{fill:url(#SVGID_133_);}
 .st133{fill:url(#SVGID_134_);}
 .st134{fill:url(#SVGID_135_);}
 .st135{fill:url(#SVGID_136_);}
 .st136{fill:url(#SVGID_137_);}
 .st137{fill:url(#SVGID_138_);}
 .st138{fill:url(#SVGID_139_);}
 .st139{fill:url(#SVGID_140_);}
 .st140{fill:url(#SVGID_141_);}
 .st141{fill:url(#SVGID_142_);}
 .st142{fill:url(#SVGID_143_);}
 .st143{fill:url(#SVGID_144_);}
 .st144{fill:url(#SVGID_145_);}
 .st145{fill:url(#SVGID_146_);}
 .st146{fill:url(#SVGID_147_);}
 .st147{fill:url(#SVGID_148_);}
 .st148{fill:url(#SVGID_149_);}
 .st149{fill:url(#SVGID_150_);}
 .st150{fill:url(#SVGID_151_);}
 .st151{fill:url(#SVGID_152_);}
 .st152{fill:url(#SVGID_153_);}
 .st153{fill:url(#SVGID_154_);}
 .st154{fill:url(#SVGID_155_);}
 .st155{fill:url(#SVGID_156_);}
 .st156{fill:url(#SVGID_157_);}
 .st157{fill:url(#SVGID_158_);}
 .st158{fill:url(#SVGID_159_);}
 .st159{fill:url(#SVGID_160_);}
 .st160{fill:url(#SVGID_161_);}
 .st161{fill:url(#SVGID_162_);}
 .st162{fill:url(#SVGID_163_);}
 .st163{fill:url(#SVGID_164_);}
 .st164{fill:url(#SVGID_165_);}
 .st165{fill:url(#SVGID_166_);}
 .st166{fill:url(#SVGID_167_);}
 .st167{fill:url(#SVGID_168_);}
 .st168{fill:url(#SVGID_169_);}
 .st169{fill:url(#SVGID_170_);}
 .st170{fill:url(#SVGID_171_);}
 .st171{fill:url(#SVGID_172_);}
 .st172{fill:url(#SVGID_173_);}
 .st173{fill:url(#SVGID_174_);}
 .st174{fill:url(#SVGID_175_);}
 .st175{fill:url(#SVGID_176_);}
 .st176{fill:url(#SVGID_177_);}
 .st177{fill:url(#SVGID_178_);}
 .st178{fill:url(#SVGID_179_);}
 .st179{fill:url(#SVGID_180_);}
 .st180{fill:url(#SVGID_181_);}
 .st181{fill:url(#SVGID_182_);}
 .st182{fill:url(#SVGID_183_);}
 .st183{fill:url(#SVGID_184_);}
 .st184{fill:url(#SVGID_185_);}
 .st185{fill:url(#SVGID_186_);}
 .st186{fill:url(#SVGID_187_);}
 .st187{fill:url(#SVGID_188_);}
 .st188{fill:url(#SVGID_189_);}
 .st189{fill:url(#SVGID_190_);}
 .st190{fill:url(#SVGID_191_);}
 .st191{fill:url(#SVGID_192_);}
 .st192{fill:url(#SVGID_193_);}
 .st193{fill:url(#SVGID_194_);}
 .st194{fill:url(#SVGID_195_);}
 .st195{fill:url(#SVGID_196_);}
 .st196{fill:url(#SVGID_197_);}
 .st197{fill:url(#SVGID_198_);}
 .st198{fill:url(#SVGID_199_);}
 .st199{fill:url(#SVGID_200_);}
 .st200{fill:url(#SVGID_201_);}
 .st201{fill:url(#SVGID_202_);}
 .st202{fill:url(#SVGID_203_);}
 .st203{fill:url(#SVGID_204_);}
 .st204{fill:url(#SVGID_205_);}
 .st205{fill:url(#SVGID_206_);}
 .st206{fill:url(#SVGID_207_);}
 .st207{fill:url(#SVGID_208_);}
 .st208{fill:url(#SVGID_209_);}
 .st209{fill:url(#SVGID_210_);}
 .st210{fill:url(#SVGID_211_);}
 .st211{fill:url(#SVGID_212_);}
 .st212{fill:url(#SVGID_213_);}
 .st213{fill:url(#SVGID_214_);}
 .st214{fill:url(#SVGID_215_);}
 .st215{fill:url(#SVGID_216_);}
 .st216{fill:url(#SVGID_217_);}
 .st217{fill:url(#SVGID_218_);}
 .st218{fill:url(#SVGID_219_);}
 .st219{fill:url(#SVGID_220_);}
 .st220{fill:url(#SVGID_221_);}
 .st221{fill:url(#SVGID_222_);}
 .st222{fill:url(#SVGID_223_);}
 .st223{fill:url(#SVGID_224_);}
 .st224{fill:url(#SVGID_225_);}
 .st225{fill:url(#SVGID_226_);}
 .st226{fill:url(#SVGID_227_);}
 .st227{fill:url(#SVGID_228_);}
 .st228{fill:url(#SVGID_229_);}
 .st229{fill:url(#SVGID_230_);}
 .st230{fill:url(#SVGID_231_);}
 .st231{fill:url(#SVGID_232_);}
 .st232{fill:url(#SVGID_233_);}
 .st233{fill:url(#SVGID_234_);}
 .st234{fill:url(#SVGID_235_);}
 .st235{fill:url(#SVGID_236_);}
 .st236{fill:url(#SVGID_237_);}
 .st237{display:none;opacity:0.36;fill:url(#SVGID_238_);}
</style>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-14699.4551" y1="15939.2051" x2="-7756.4546" y2="8913.5049" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A3246E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#9E2350"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st0" points="564.7,284.7 367.9,170.4 490.5,369.6  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-13639.6572" y1="16689.8086" x2="-5237.6577" y2="13221.6074" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B33649"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#AA2342"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st1" points="644.9,177.5 367.9,170.4 564.7,284.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-8122.2817" y1="15235.3623" x2="-3133.2817" y2="11452.0625" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C13F4D"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#CA3A46"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st2" points="706.2,210.5 644.9,177.5 564.7,284.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-6970.895" y1="14968.877" x2="-1223.8953" y2="8463.1768" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C65059"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D15962"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st3" points="734.5,402.6 706.2,210.5 564.7,284.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-5094.6514" y1="16566.1113" x2="-2932.6514" y2="14362.7119" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C62D46"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C62D48"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st4" points="706.2,210.5 664.9,148 644.9,177.5  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="17507.7129" y1="-4080.5278" x2="26151.7129" y2="-7896.5278" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CF62D1"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#BF4BAF"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st5" points="1255.4,804.5 1519.3,882.2 1527.6,762  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_7_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="17485.4785" y1="-6247.9624" x2="25680.4785" y2="-11552.9619" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CF6BDB"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C864C8"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st6" points="1453.4,975.3 1519.3,882.2 1255.4,804.5  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_8_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="23660.0703" y1="-9167.4619" x2="25988.0703" y2="-13158.4619" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C36BC6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C364C3"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st7" points="1453.4,975.3 1488.7,995.4 1519.3,882.2  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_9_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-10094.6826" y1="11673.9619" x2="-5734.6831" y2="5438.9614" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B3368E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C14B8C"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st8" points="564.7,284.7 490.5,369.6 624.9,476.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_10_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-8158.1108" y1="11301.4336" x2="-2411.1108" y2="4795.4331" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C14972"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D1629A"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st9" points="734.5,402.6 564.7,284.7 624.9,476.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_11_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-16312.25" y1="149.4167" x2="-10034.25" y2="-6128.583" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#740E8C"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#831A9E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st10" points="377.4,581.7 358.5,736.1 536.5,759.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_12_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-15386.876" y1="7738.0195" x2="-6655.8765" y2="254.0198" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B1348E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#A83895"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st11" points="490.5,369.6 377.4,581.7 624.9,476.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_13_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="4292.6904" y1="846.5754" x2="7867.6899" y2="-3269.4243" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#D862BA"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#E670B6"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st12" points="1006.7,594.7 910.1,711.4 1011.4,617.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_14_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="16024.8516" y1="-3447.8586" x2="25628.8516" y2="-7647.8589" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CD62C8"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C14F9C"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st13" points="1316.6,685.4 1255.4,804.5 1527.6,762  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_15_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="19289.166" y1="1695.8986" x2="28519.1641" y2="-4041.1011" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#AF3880"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#AF3D7E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st14" points="1527.6,762 1578.3,599.4 1316.6,685.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_16_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-26340.3047" y1="21975.1309" x2="-25247.2051" y2="18182.5703" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5D053B"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#540334"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st15" points="62.7,103.2 75.5,0 55.5,0 29.7,78.5  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_17_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-13181.1738" y1="2261.2271" x2="-4126.1743" y2="-3388.7725" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#85168C"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#AC42C4"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st16" points="377.4,581.7 536.5,759.7 662.6,584.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_18_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-14218.7432" y1="4748.9004" x2="-4761.7437" y2="1191.9005" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#95288E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C65DBA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st17" points="624.9,476.8 377.4,581.7 662.6,584.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_19_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-9543.2725" y1="292.8513" x2="-1021.2733" y2="-5902.1484" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#AC49DD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C162D1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st18" points="536.5,759.7 778.1,694.9 662.6,584.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_20_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="25756.1797" y1="-7026.1777" x2="33474.1797" y2="-10833.1777" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B850B3"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#AF4DAA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st19" points="1519.3,882.2 1779.8,890.5 1527.6,762  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_21_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="34433.8711" y1="22258.1602" x2="40236.8711" y2="19932.9199" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#4F033F"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5D084D"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st20" points="1920,30.9 1920,0 1758.7,0 1845.8,73.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_22_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="34139.6289" y1="18643.1387" x2="39572.6289" y2="8736.0391" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#620346"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#4B0538"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st21" points="1786.9,366.1 1920,239.8 1920,176.5 1845.8,73.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_23_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="37629.2539" y1="21010.2949" x2="41231.2539" y2="16695.3945" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#560A49"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#640A56"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st22" points="1920,176.5 1920,30.9 1845.8,73.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_24_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-9645.3438" y1="-5916.04" x2="-4104.3438" y2="-11050.04" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A13BDD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#9736D1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st23" points="588.3,905.8 696.8,908.2 536.5,759.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_25_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-7600.4663" y1="-1243.704" x2="921.5334" y2="-8768.7031" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A33DDD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#A544CC"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st24" points="536.5,759.7 696.8,908.2 778.1,694.9  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_26_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-6503.6294" y1="-9643.7969" x2="-2908.6294" y2="-12300.7969" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#9533CD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8C28BA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st25" points="588.3,905.8 654.3,985.9 696.8,908.2  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_27_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="25705.3301" y1="164.1296" x2="33313.3281" y2="-5572.8701" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#9A247E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8C1672"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st26" points="1527.6,762 1743.3,648.9 1578.3,599.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_28_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26948.3184" y1="-165.785" x2="35845.3164" y2="-8687.7852" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A1318A"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#A13D9E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st27" points="1779.8,890.5 1743.3,648.9 1527.6,762  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_29_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="34026.6406" y1="-1312.1631" x2="38730.6406" y2="-9154.1631" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B152B5"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#9C2A8E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st28" points="1779.8,890.5 1888.2,698.4 1743.3,648.9  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_30_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="7481.1182" y1="4684.3765" x2="9726.1182" y2="735.3764" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#EB91B6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#EFB3B6"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st29" points="1070.3,518.1 1044.4,482.7 1006.7,594.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_31_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="7807.7271" y1="3627.4224" x2="10052.7266" y2="135.4223" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E982B3"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#EB90B5"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st30" points="1011.4,617.1 1070.3,518.1 1006.7,594.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_32_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="7710.7119" y1="2734.3523" x2="13906.7119" y2="-1702.6478" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#EB7EB6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#ED93BA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st31" points="1202.3,654.8 1070.3,518.1 1011.4,617.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_33_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="35219.4688" y1="-2674.1736" x2="39044.4688" y2="-10448.1738" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#BA5EC6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B650BA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st32" points="1870.5,918.8 1888.2,698.4 1779.8,890.5  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_34_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="37431.2656" y1="-5202.9653" x2="40264.2656" y2="-8534.9658" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#AF3FA5"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C860CA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st33" points="1870.5,918.8 1920,900.7 1920,726.9 1888.2,698.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_35_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="5181.6489" y1="81.094" x2="9072.6484" y2="-6691.9058" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#D160BD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D362C1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st34" points="910.1,711.4 1032.6,830.4 1011.4,617.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_36_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="7859.9673" y1="-87.4371" x2="14459.9678" y2="-7462.437" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E672C3"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D86DCA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st35" points="1011.4,617.1 1032.6,830.4 1202.3,654.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_37_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="16199.8867" y1="-12308.8564" x2="20809.8867" y2="-14394.8564" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#AF56B6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B160B3"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st36" points="1234.1,971.8 1334.3,1039 1382.6,1000.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_38_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="16123.0303" y1="-6916.147" x2="23108.0293" y2="-13817.1475" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CA70D6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C16DC1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st37" points="1255.4,804.5 1382.6,1000.1 1453.4,975.3  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_39_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="19307" y1="-13248.333" x2="24753" y2="-14786.333" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B160B1"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#BA6BBA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st38" points="1382.6,1000.1 1334.3,1039 1488.7,995.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_40_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="20978.8164" y1="-12679.2861" x2="24720.8164" y2="-13552.2861" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C16DC1"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#BD6DBF"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st39" points="1382.6,1000.1 1488.7,995.4 1453.4,975.3  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_41_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="14918.7852" y1="2961.0852" x2="19492.7852" y2="-2068.915" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E279AA"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D36783"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st40" points="1316.6,685.4 1332,542.8 1202.3,654.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_42_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="18448.7969" y1="1847.6938" x2="27308.7969" y2="-2982.3059" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CA597E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B63F62"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st41" points="1578.3,599.4 1332,542.8 1316.6,685.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_43_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="10967.668" y1="4529.6211" x2="15623.668" y2="-293.3789" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#F0A5B1"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#ED90AF"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st42" points="1192.9,534.6 1070.3,518.1 1202.3,654.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_44_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="14365.7578" y1="2964.2297" x2="19173.7578" y2="-1191.7705" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E883AC"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#E28085"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st43" points="1332,542.8 1192.9,534.6 1202.3,654.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_45_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="35374.6914" y1="-9364.8174" x2="38447.6914" y2="-12836.8174" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C175DB"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C67CE6"/>
 </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [CSS / SVG / Animation : Apply transform origin to a single element within svg not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51599667/7394871) от участника  [@HelloWorld0815](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3445825/helloworld0815).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51599667/7394871

Answer (score 3):

По умолчанию `transform-origin: 50%, 50%` означает центр всего SVG.

Если вы хотите, чтобы он обозначал центр каждого элемента, вы можете указать это с помощью свойства `transform-box:fill-box`

```
polygon, polyline {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

Это относительно новое свойство, которое работает в последних версиях Chrome, Firefox и Opera. Но не в Edge.

```js
anime({
  targets: 'polygon, polyline',
  scale: [0.1, 1],
  opacity: [0.1, 1],
  rotate: '1turn',
  duration: 7000
});
```

```css
body, html{
  margin:0
}
svg, g {
  transform-origin: unset unset;
}

polygon, polyline {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1"
  id="heroSvg" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   viewBox="0 0 1920 1300"
  style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1300;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:url(#SVGID_1_);}
 .st1{fill:url(#SVGID_2_);}
 .st2{fill:url(#SVGID_3_);}
 .st3{fill:url(#SVGID_4_);}
 .st4{fill:url(#SVGID_5_);}
 .st5{fill:url(#SVGID_6_);}
 .st6{fill:url(#SVGID_7_);}
 .st7{fill:url(#SVGID_8_);}
 .st8{fill:url(#SVGID_9_);}
 .st9{fill:url(#SVGID_10_);}
 .st10{fill:url(#SVGID_11_);}
 .st11{fill:url(#SVGID_12_);}
 .st12{fill:url(#SVGID_13_);}
 .st13{fill:url(#SVGID_14_);}
 .st14{fill:url(#SVGID_15_);}
 .st15{fill:url(#SVGID_16_);}
 .st16{fill:url(#SVGID_17_);}
 .st17{fill:url(#SVGID_18_);}
 .st18{fill:url(#SVGID_19_);}
 .st19{fill:url(#SVGID_20_);}
 .st20{fill:url(#SVGID_21_);}
 .st21{fill:url(#SVGID_22_);}
 .st22{fill:url(#SVGID_23_);}
 .st23{fill:url(#SVGID_24_);}
 .st24{fill:url(#SVGID_25_);}
 .st25{fill:url(#SVGID_26_);}
 .st26{fill:url(#SVGID_27_);}
 .st27{fill:url(#SVGID_28_);}
 .st28{fill:url(#SVGID_29_);}
 .st29{fill:url(#SVGID_30_);}
 .st30{fill:url(#SVGID_31_);}
 .st31{fill:url(#SVGID_32_);}
 .st32{fill:url(#SVGID_33_);}
 .st33{fill:url(#SVGID_34_);}
 .st34{fill:url(#SVGID_35_);}
 .st35{fill:url(#SVGID_36_);}
 .st36{fill:url(#SVGID_37_);}
 .st37{fill:url(#SVGID_38_);}
 .st38{fill:url(#SVGID_39_);}
 .st39{fill:url(#SVGID_40_);}
 .st40{fill:url(#SVGID_41_);}
 .st41{fill:url(#SVGID_42_);}
 .st42{fill:url(#SVGID_43_);}
 .st43{fill:url(#SVGID_44_);}
 .st44{fill:url(#SVGID_45_);}
 .st45{fill:url(#SVGID_46_);}
 .st46{fill:url(#SVGID_47_);}
 .st47{fill:url(#SVGID_48_);}
 .st48{fill:url(#SVGID_49_);}
 .st49{fill:url(#SVGID_50_);}
 .st50{fill:url(#SVGID_51_);}
 .st51{fill:url(#SVGID_52_);}
 .st52{fill:url(#SVGID_53_);}
 .st53{fill:url(#SVGID_54_);}
 .st54{fill:url(#SVGID_55_);}
 .st55{fill:url(#SVGID_56_);}
 .st56{fill:url(#SVGID_57_);}
 .st57{fill:url(#SVGID_58_);}
 .st58{fill:url(#SVGID_59_);}
 .st59{fill:url(#SVGID_60_);}
 .st60{fill:url(#SVGID_61_);}
 .st61{fill:url(#SVGID_62_);}
 .st62{fill:url(#SVGID_63_);}
 .st63{fill:url(#SVGID_64_);}
 .st64{fill:url(#SVGID_65_);}
 .st65{fill:url(#SVGID_66_);}
 .st66{fill:url(#SVGID_67_);}
 .st67{fill:url(#SVGID_68_);}
 .st68{fill:url(#SVGID_69_);}
 .st69{fill:url(#SVGID_70_);}
 .st70{fill:url(#SVGID_71_);}
 .st71{fill:url(#SVGID_72_);}
 .st72{fill:url(#SVGID_73_);}
 .st73{fill:url(#SVGID_74_);}
 .st74{fill:url(#SVGID_75_);}
 .st75{fill:url(#SVGID_76_);}
 .st76{fill:url(#SVGID_77_);}
 .st77{fill:url(#SVGID_78_);}
 .st78{fill:url(#SVGID_79_);}
 .st79{fill:url(#SVGID_80_);}
 .st80{fill:url(#SVGID_81_);}
 .st81{fill:url(#SVGID_82_);}
 .st82{fill:url(#SVGID_83_);}
 .st83{fill:url(#SVGID_84_);}
 .st84{fill:url(#SVGID_85_);}
 .st85{fill:url(#SVGID_86_);}
 .st86{fill:url(#SVGID_87_);}
 .st87{fill:url(#SVGID_88_);}
 .st88{fill:url(#SVGID_89_);}
 .st89{fill:url(#SVGID_90_);}
 .st90{fill:url(#SVGID_91_);}
 .st91{fill:url(#SVGID_92_);}
 .st92{fill:url(#SVGID_93_);}
 .st93{fill:url(#SVGID_94_);}
 .st94{fill:url(#SVGID_95_);}
 .st95{fill:url(#SVGID_96_);}
 .st96{fill:url(#SVGID_97_);}
 .st97{fill:url(#SVGID_98_);}
 .st98{fill:url(#SVGID_99_);}
 .st99{fill:url(#SVGID_100_);}
 .st100{fill:url(#SVGID_101_);}
 .st101{fill:url(#SVGID_102_);}
 .st102{fill:url(#SVGID_103_);}
 .st103{fill:url(#SVGID_104_);}
 .st104{fill:url(#SVGID_105_);}
 .st105{fill:url(#SVGID_106_);}
 .st106{fill:url(#SVGID_107_);}
 .st107{fill:url(#SVGID_108_);}
 .st108{fill:url(#SVGID_109_);}
 .st109{fill:url(#SVGID_110_);}
 .st110{fill:url(#SVGID_111_);}
 .st111{fill:url(#SVGID_112_);}
 .st112{fill:url(#SVGID_113_);}
 .st113{fill:url(#SVGID_114_);}
 .st114{fill:url(#SVGID_115_);}
 .st115{fill:url(#SVGID_116_);}
 .st116{fill:url(#SVGID_117_);}
 .st117{fill:url(#SVGID_118_);}
 .st118{fill:url(#SVGID_119_);}
 .st119{fill:url(#SVGID_120_);}
 .st120{fill:url(#SVGID_121_);}
 .st121{fill:url(#SVGID_122_);}
 .st122{fill:url(#SVGID_123_);}
 .st123{fill:url(#SVGID_124_);}
 .st124{fill:url(#SVGID_125_);}
 .st125{fill:url(#SVGID_126_);}
 .st126{fill:url(#SVGID_127_);}
 .st127{fill:url(#SVGID_128_);}
 .st128{fill:url(#SVGID_129_);}
 .st129{fill:url(#SVGID_130_);}
 .st130{fill:url(#SVGID_131_);}
 .st131{fill:url(#SVGID_132_);}
 .st132{fill:url(#SVGID_133_);}
 .st133{fill:url(#SVGID_134_);}
 .st134{fill:url(#SVGID_135_);}
 .st135{fill:url(#SVGID_136_);}
 .st136{fill:url(#SVGID_137_);}
 .st137{fill:url(#SVGID_138_);}
 .st138{fill:url(#SVGID_139_);}
 .st139{fill:url(#SVGID_140_);}
 .st140{fill:url(#SVGID_141_);}
 .st141{fill:url(#SVGID_142_);}
 .st142{fill:url(#SVGID_143_);}
 .st143{fill:url(#SVGID_144_);}
 .st144{fill:url(#SVGID_145_);}
 .st145{fill:url(#SVGID_146_);}
 .st146{fill:url(#SVGID_147_);}
 .st147{fill:url(#SVGID_148_);}
 .st148{fill:url(#SVGID_149_);}
 .st149{fill:url(#SVGID_150_);}
 .st150{fill:url(#SVGID_151_);}
 .st151{fill:url(#SVGID_152_);}
 .st152{fill:url(#SVGID_153_);}
 .st153{fill:url(#SVGID_154_);}
 .st154{fill:url(#SVGID_155_);}
 .st155{fill:url(#SVGID_156_);}
 .st156{fill:url(#SVGID_157_);}
 .st157{fill:url(#SVGID_158_);}
 .st158{fill:url(#SVGID_159_);}
 .st159{fill:url(#SVGID_160_);}
 .st160{fill:url(#SVGID_161_);}
 .st161{fill:url(#SVGID_162_);}
 .st162{fill:url(#SVGID_163_);}
 .st163{fill:url(#SVGID_164_);}
 .st164{fill:url(#SVGID_165_);}
 .st165{fill:url(#SVGID_166_);}
 .st166{fill:url(#SVGID_167_);}
 .st167{fill:url(#SVGID_168_);}
 .st168{fill:url(#SVGID_169_);}
 .st169{fill:url(#SVGID_170_);}
 .st170{fill:url(#SVGID_171_);}
 .st171{fill:url(#SVGID_172_);}
 .st172{fill:url(#SVGID_173_);}
 .st173{fill:url(#SVGID_174_);}
 .st174{fill:url(#SVGID_175_);}
 .st175{fill:url(#SVGID_176_);}
 .st176{fill:url(#SVGID_177_);}
 .st177{fill:url(#SVGID_178_);}
 .st178{fill:url(#SVGID_179_);}
 .st179{fill:url(#SVGID_180_);}
 .st180{fill:url(#SVGID_181_);}
 .st181{fill:url(#SVGID_182_);}
 .st182{fill:url(#SVGID_183_);}
 .st183{fill:url(#SVGID_184_);}
 .st184{fill:url(#SVGID_185_);}
 .st185{fill:url(#SVGID_186_);}
 .st186{fill:url(#SVGID_187_);}
 .st187{fill:url(#SVGID_188_);}
 .st188{fill:url(#SVGID_189_);}
 .st189{fill:url(#SVGID_190_);}
 .st190{fill:url(#SVGID_191_);}
 .st191{fill:url(#SVGID_192_);}
 .st192{fill:url(#SVGID_193_);}
 .st193{fill:url(#SVGID_194_);}
 .st194{fill:url(#SVGID_195_);}
 .st195{fill:url(#SVGID_196_);}
 .st196{fill:url(#SVGID_197_);}
 .st197{fill:url(#SVGID_198_);}
 .st198{fill:url(#SVGID_199_);}
 .st199{fill:url(#SVGID_200_);}
 .st200{fill:url(#SVGID_201_);}
 .st201{fill:url(#SVGID_202_);}
 .st202{fill:url(#SVGID_203_);}
 .st203{fill:url(#SVGID_204_);}
 .st204{fill:url(#SVGID_205_);}
 .st205{fill:url(#SVGID_206_);}
 .st206{fill:url(#SVGID_207_);}
 .st207{fill:url(#SVGID_208_);}
 .st208{fill:url(#SVGID_209_);}
 .st209{fill:url(#SVGID_210_);}
 .st210{fill:url(#SVGID_211_);}
 .st211{fill:url(#SVGID_212_);}
 .st212{fill:url(#SVGID_213_);}
 .st213{fill:url(#SVGID_214_);}
 .st214{fill:url(#SVGID_215_);}
 .st215{fill:url(#SVGID_216_);}
 .st216{fill:url(#SVGID_217_);}
 .st217{fill:url(#SVGID_218_);}
 .st218{fill:url(#SVGID_219_);}
 .st219{fill:url(#SVGID_220_);}
 .st220{fill:url(#SVGID_221_);}
 .st221{fill:url(#SVGID_222_);}
 .st222{fill:url(#SVGID_223_);}
 .st223{fill:url(#SVGID_224_);}
 .st224{fill:url(#SVGID_225_);}
 .st225{fill:url(#SVGID_226_);}
 .st226{fill:url(#SVGID_227_);}
 .st227{fill:url(#SVGID_228_);}
 .st228{fill:url(#SVGID_229_);}
 .st229{fill:url(#SVGID_230_);}
 .st230{fill:url(#SVGID_231_);}
 .st231{fill:url(#SVGID_232_);}
 .st232{fill:url(#SVGID_233_);}
 .st233{fill:url(#SVGID_234_);}
 .st234{fill:url(#SVGID_235_);}
 .st235{fill:url(#SVGID_236_);}
 .st236{fill:url(#SVGID_237_);}
 .st237{display:none;opacity:0.36;fill:url(#SVGID_238_);}
</style>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-14699.4551" y1="15939.2051" x2="-7756.4546" y2="8913.5049" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A3246E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#9E2350"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st0" points="564.7,284.7 367.9,170.4 490.5,369.6  "/>
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-13639.6572" y1="16689.8086" x2="-5237.6577" y2="13221.6074" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B33649"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#AA2342"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st1" points="644.9,177.5 367.9,170.4 564.7,284.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-8122.2817" y1="15235.3623" x2="-3133.2817" y2="11452.0625" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C13F4D"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#CA3A46"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st2" points="706.2,210.5 644.9,177.5 564.7,284.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-6970.895" y1="14968.877" x2="-1223.8953" y2="8463.1768" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C65059"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D15962"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st3" points="734.5,402.6 706.2,210.5 564.7,284.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-5094.6514" y1="16566.1113" x2="-2932.6514" y2="14362.7119" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C62D46"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C62D48"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st4" points="706.2,210.5 664.9,148 644.9,177.5  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_6_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="17507.7129" y1="-4080.5278" x2="26151.7129" y2="-7896.5278" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CF62D1"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#BF4BAF"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st5" points="1255.4,804.5 1519.3,882.2 1527.6,762  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_7_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="17485.4785" y1="-6247.9624" x2="25680.4785" y2="-11552.9619" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CF6BDB"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C864C8"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st6" points="1453.4,975.3 1519.3,882.2 1255.4,804.5  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_8_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="23660.0703" y1="-9167.4619" x2="25988.0703" y2="-13158.4619" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C36BC6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C364C3"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st7" points="1453.4,975.3 1488.7,995.4 1519.3,882.2  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_9_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-10094.6826" y1="11673.9619" x2="-5734.6831" y2="5438.9614" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B3368E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C14B8C"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st8" points="564.7,284.7 490.5,369.6 624.9,476.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_10_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-8158.1108" y1="11301.4336" x2="-2411.1108" y2="4795.4331" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C14972"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D1629A"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st9" points="734.5,402.6 564.7,284.7 624.9,476.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_11_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-16312.25" y1="149.4167" x2="-10034.25" y2="-6128.583" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#740E8C"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#831A9E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st10" points="377.4,581.7 358.5,736.1 536.5,759.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_12_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-15386.876" y1="7738.0195" x2="-6655.8765" y2="254.0198" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B1348E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#A83895"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st11" points="490.5,369.6 377.4,581.7 624.9,476.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_13_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="4292.6904" y1="846.5754" x2="7867.6899" y2="-3269.4243" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#D862BA"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#E670B6"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st12" points="1006.7,594.7 910.1,711.4 1011.4,617.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_14_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="16024.8516" y1="-3447.8586" x2="25628.8516" y2="-7647.8589" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CD62C8"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C14F9C"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st13" points="1316.6,685.4 1255.4,804.5 1527.6,762  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_15_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="19289.166" y1="1695.8986" x2="28519.1641" y2="-4041.1011" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#AF3880"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#AF3D7E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st14" points="1527.6,762 1578.3,599.4 1316.6,685.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_16_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-26340.3047" y1="21975.1309" x2="-25247.2051" y2="18182.5703" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#5D053B"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#540334"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st15" points="62.7,103.2 75.5,0 55.5,0 29.7,78.5  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_17_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-13181.1738" y1="2261.2271" x2="-4126.1743" y2="-3388.7725" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#85168C"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#AC42C4"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st16" points="377.4,581.7 536.5,759.7 662.6,584.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_18_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-14218.7432" y1="4748.9004" x2="-4761.7437" y2="1191.9005" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#95288E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C65DBA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st17" points="624.9,476.8 377.4,581.7 662.6,584.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_19_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-9543.2725" y1="292.8513" x2="-1021.2733" y2="-5902.1484" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#AC49DD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C162D1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st18" points="536.5,759.7 778.1,694.9 662.6,584.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_20_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="25756.1797" y1="-7026.1777" x2="33474.1797" y2="-10833.1777" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B850B3"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#AF4DAA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st19" points="1519.3,882.2 1779.8,890.5 1527.6,762  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_21_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="34433.8711" y1="22258.1602" x2="40236.8711" y2="19932.9199" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#4F033F"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#5D084D"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st20" points="1920,30.9 1920,0 1758.7,0 1845.8,73.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_22_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="34139.6289" y1="18643.1387" x2="39572.6289" y2="8736.0391" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#620346"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#4B0538"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st21" points="1786.9,366.1 1920,239.8 1920,176.5 1845.8,73.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_23_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="37629.2539" y1="21010.2949" x2="41231.2539" y2="16695.3945" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#560A49"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#640A56"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st22" points="1920,176.5 1920,30.9 1845.8,73.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_24_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-9645.3438" y1="-5916.04" x2="-4104.3438" y2="-11050.04" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A13BDD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#9736D1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st23" points="588.3,905.8 696.8,908.2 536.5,759.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_25_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-7600.4663" y1="-1243.704" x2="921.5334" y2="-8768.7031" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A33DDD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#A544CC"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st24" points="536.5,759.7 696.8,908.2 778.1,694.9  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_26_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="-6503.6294" y1="-9643.7969" x2="-2908.6294" y2="-12300.7969" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#9533CD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8C28BA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st25" points="588.3,905.8 654.3,985.9 696.8,908.2  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_27_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="25705.3301" y1="164.1296" x2="33313.3281" y2="-5572.8701" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#9A247E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8C1672"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st26" points="1527.6,762 1743.3,648.9 1578.3,599.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_28_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="26948.3184" y1="-165.785" x2="35845.3164" y2="-8687.7852" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#A1318A"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#A13D9E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st27" points="1779.8,890.5 1743.3,648.9 1527.6,762  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_29_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="34026.6406" y1="-1312.1631" x2="38730.6406" y2="-9154.1631" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B152B5"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#9C2A8E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st28" points="1779.8,890.5 1888.2,698.4 1743.3,648.9  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_30_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="7481.1182" y1="4684.3765" x2="9726.1182" y2="735.3764" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#EB91B6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#EFB3B6"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st29" points="1070.3,518.1 1044.4,482.7 1006.7,594.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_31_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="7807.7271" y1="3627.4224" x2="10052.7266" y2="135.4223" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E982B3"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#EB90B5"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st30" points="1011.4,617.1 1070.3,518.1 1006.7,594.7  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_32_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="7710.7119" y1="2734.3523" x2="13906.7119" y2="-1702.6478" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#EB7EB6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#ED93BA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st31" points="1202.3,654.8 1070.3,518.1 1011.4,617.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_33_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="35219.4688" y1="-2674.1736" x2="39044.4688" y2="-10448.1738" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#BA5EC6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B650BA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st32" points="1870.5,918.8 1888.2,698.4 1779.8,890.5  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_34_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="37431.2656" y1="-5202.9653" x2="40264.2656" y2="-8534.9658" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#AF3FA5"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C860CA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st33" points="1870.5,918.8 1920,900.7 1920,726.9 1888.2,698.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_35_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="5181.6489" y1="81.094" x2="9072.6484" y2="-6691.9058" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#D160BD"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D362C1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st34" points="910.1,711.4 1032.6,830.4 1011.4,617.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_36_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="7859.9673" y1="-87.4371" x2="14459.9678" y2="-7462.437" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E672C3"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D86DCA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st35" points="1011.4,617.1 1032.6,830.4 1202.3,654.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_37_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="16199.8867" y1="-12308.8564" x2="20809.8867" y2="-14394.8564" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#AF56B6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B160B3"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st36" points="1234.1,971.8 1334.3,1039 1382.6,1000.1  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_38_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="16123.0303" y1="-6916.147" x2="23108.0293" y2="-13817.1475" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CA70D6"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C16DC1"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st37" points="1255.4,804.5 1382.6,1000.1 1453.4,975.3  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_39_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="19307" y1="-13248.333" x2="24753" y2="-14786.333" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#B160B1"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#BA6BBA"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st38" points="1382.6,1000.1 1334.3,1039 1488.7,995.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_40_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="20978.8164" y1="-12679.2861" x2="24720.8164" y2="-13552.2861" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C16DC1"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#BD6DBF"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st39" points="1382.6,1000.1 1488.7,995.4 1453.4,975.3  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_41_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="14918.7852" y1="2961.0852" x2="19492.7852" y2="-2068.915" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E279AA"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#D36783"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st40" points="1316.6,685.4 1332,542.8 1202.3,654.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_42_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="18448.7969" y1="1847.6938" x2="27308.7969" y2="-2982.3059" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#CA597E"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#B63F62"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st41" points="1578.3,599.4 1332,542.8 1316.6,685.4  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_43_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="10967.668" y1="4529.6211" x2="15623.668" y2="-293.3789" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#F0A5B1"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#ED90AF"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st42" points="1192.9,534.6 1070.3,518.1 1202.3,654.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_44_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="14365.7578" y1="2964.2297" x2="19173.7578" y2="-1191.7705" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#E883AC"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#E28085"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <polygon class="st43" points="1332,542.8 1192.9,534.6 1202.3,654.8  "/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_45_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="35374.6914" y1="-9364.8174" x2="38447.6914" y2="-12836.8174" gradientTransform="matrix(2.834646e-02 0 0 -2.834646e-02 787.0394 619.8425)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#C175DB"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#C67CE6"/>
 </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [CSS / SVG / Animation : Apply transform origin to a single element within svg not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51600200/7394871)
 от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>